# auto upload and set featured image to wordpress post based on external url

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I have a music website based on soundcloud api , 
I have custom post type called albums and each post is a track,
at the moment i can get all the details i need from soundcloud track as well as the track image url. 
How can i use this url from soundcloud and make wordpress download that image and set it as the post featured image?

I have tried and searched over the net and couldn't find nothing on how auto upload and publish external featured image.
Any help would be perfect!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this extension for WordPress:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-remote-thumbnail/
http://magnigenie.com/wp-remote-thumbnail-set-external-images-featured-image/

Comment: is there a way to use one of the post custom fields as the input?

Comment: well after some test, i found that everytime i update a post withot an image the plugin creates an empty file in my media library, any idiea how to prevent it?

Comment: ask the author on his website magniegenie

Comment: @Yaya replace this 
`delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id' ); 
add_post_meta( $post_id , '_thumbnail_id' , $attach_id, true);` 

by this 

`if ($_POST['remote_thumb']) {
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) { delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id' ); }
    add_post_meta( $post_id , '_thumbnail_id' , $attach_id, true); }
if ( (has_post_thumbnail()) && (!isset($_POST['remote_thumb'])) ) { return ; }`

in the plugin file `wp-remote-thumbnail.php`